# Finding palindromes of real words

Tags: algorithm

I just read the question [Anagram of a Palindrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447222/anagram-of-a-palindrome) which lead me to some other palindrome questions.  But when I think of a palindrome, I think of real world palindromes that use real words from a language and make some degree of sense in that language.

So, if we give up on grammar and meaning as too difficult, what we be a good algorithm for finding palindromes that are comprised of words in a dictionary?  You can pre-process the dictionary into a data structure that makes it easier.  You can't pre-process the dictionary by finding every possible palindrome, unless you've got a way to do that in a realistic amount of computing time and space.

Assume you want to find palindromes up to 100,000 characters and you have a dictionary of 100,000 lower case English words.

Bonus points if you can come up with a way to quickly find anagrams of palindromes as well.  I'm not sure there is a feasible way to do that though.

Edit - there seems to be some confusion, so I must not have been clear enough.  I'm looking for sequences of words (up to 100,000 characters in length) that are palindromes, not single dictionary words, which is a trivial problem.  So, any number of "a"s or "i"s are palindroms, since each one is word and the sequence is a palindrome. "amanaplanacanalpanama" is also a palindrome, because "a", "man", "plan", "canal", and "panama" are words (if "panama" is really in this dictionary)

Comment: Is this an interview or a question?

Comment: how many real-world words contain up to 100,000 characters?

Comment: @DMactheDestroyer I believe he meant you can combine real works out of the dictionary to form palindromes up to 100,000 characters in length, if we take out the context of the grammer not making sense.

Comment: @DanW - Yes, that is exactly what I mean.  Added edit since I apparently did quite a bad job of making that clear.  My apologies.

Comment: You're still not asking a question...

Comment: @AustinSalonen - What would be a good algorithm for for finding palindromes that are comprised of words in a dictionary?  (It would be nice if it handles anagrams of palindromes efficiently, but that's not the core question).

Comment: That should be part of the question...

Comment: @AustinSalonen- "What would be a good algorithm for for finding palindromes that are comprised of words in a dictionary?" is literally a substring of the question text.

Comment: @DMactheDestroyer I believe that'd be all of them ;)

Comment: Does anyone voting to close want to explain how a request for an algorithm isn't related so programming or software development, as defined in the faq?

Answer (score 0):

In C# I would use LINQ to transform the given strings...

```
public bool isPalindrome(string str){
    var rev= new string(Enumerable.Range(1, str.Length).Select(i => str[str.Length - i]).ToArray());
    return String.Compare(str, rev, true);
}
```

That part is easy, but would take some tuning for performance if you were to attack 100,000 character lengths. One might chop the string in half and flip the second half to speed up the reversing process and shortening the compared strings.

From there, I'd dump every discovered palindrome into an `IEnumerable` collection, and test them against your pre-defined dictionary... again, the key that i've not addressed is performance.

EDIT: A better performance option (credit to http://www.softwareandfinance.com/CSharp/Palindrome.html)

```
static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
{
    bool palindrome = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length / 2 + 1; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] != s[s.Length - i-1])
        {
            palindrome = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return palindrome;
}
```

This approach assumes the word is a palindrome (possibly dangerous) but compares letter to letter of the string until there is not a match. Odd letter words are taken care of. In my approach above, splitting in half you would have to grab the half + 1 in order to compare apples to apples.

That what you were looking for?

Comment: It's not trying to find all the words in a dictionary that are palindromes, which is trivial, but to find all the sequences of words up to 100,000 character that are palindromes.  So, any number of "a"s or "i"s are palindroms, since each one is word and the sequence is a palindrome.  "amanaplanacanalpanama" is also a palindrome, because "a", "man", "plan", "canal", and "panama" are words (if "panama" is really in this dictionary).

Comment: You said you wanted to find palindromes and detect if they were "real word palindromes" in a dictionary. I'm not sure I understand your question then. If you want to find "real dictionary words, inside a palindrome, then you would check for each word in your dictionary, if that string contains the sequence of chars - but that has nothing to do with palindromes itself.

Comment: I want to detect whether a given string is a palindrome comprised of words from a given dictionary.  I want the algorithm to be efficient.  How can I efficiently tell if "amanaplanacanalpanama" is a palindrome?  Note that it would not be considered one if "panama" isn't in the dictionary (according to my definition of palindrome, which requires not only the string be reversible, but composed of words both directions).

Comment: You already know that it is a palindrome. Trying to find all the possible real word combinations within a palindrome of that size is silly. The anagram of a palindrome question was mainly a puzzle to see if the programmer was sharp enough to see the problem at hand. Your question is comes off superfluous at this point.

Comment: I kind of thought the original problem could be described a superfluous.  Almost a trick question, since non programmers mean "composed of real words" when talking about palindromes (though they defined it).  I think anything about palindromes is pretty much going to be silly (after all, they are pretty much useless), but finding real world combinations seems more of test of programming skill to me.  A matter of taste, I guess.  Sorry you went to the trouble of writing code when I hadn't yet made the question clear.

Comment: Not a problem at all; I'm new here and trying to build some rep, so I don't mind trying where I can. :)  And you're right, it was definitely a trick question for the interview. Toss language "real words" out the door and there are still plenty of reasons to use palindromes (numbers or characters) I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking that if I really wanted to efficiently check the dictionary at run time at the expense of some work at compile time then I would build a state machine to check if a sequence of letters was in the dictionary.  I could build this by reading each dictionary entry, then letter by letter creating a new state if one didn't exist.

So, if the first word in the dictionary was "a", going from start state to "a" state on reading an "a" would be a valid transition.  If the next word was "axe", I would create a transition from "a" to "ax" on "x", and from "ax" to "axe" on on "e".  States "a" and "axe" would be accept states, but not "ax".

This would be a non-deterministic state machine, with transitions from any accept to the start state allowed (since after reading "axe" I might read an "a", and "axea" is in the language of strings of complete words that can be found in the dictionary).

I would then optimize the state machine into a deterministic state machine using well known techniques (really using somebody else's code, since this code has surely been written over 1,000 times).

At run time, I would run the possible palindrome through the state machine forwards, and, if it passes forwards, backwards.

I have no idea what would be a good way to find anagrams of palindromes.